# Does reverting to an old save remove newer saves?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm experiencing a problem and after doing some research I've concluded the only way for me to fix it is to go back to an old save.  I'm level 55 now, I was level 32 when I started that mission.

If I save now and go back to an old save will my newest saves be deleted?  I'd like to keep them around at least for a while if possible

Answer (score 3):

Manual saves are not deleted. The only thing that gets overwritten is the autosave file.

You can literally save the game 50 times and they will always be there for you to load back into.